# Изменение содержимого переменной через регулярку

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Вот суть проблемы.

Есть некая переменная `text`, в которой находится какой-то код, нужно найти в этой переменной (именно в переменной, а не в DOM) все теги `div` и удалить у них все атрибуты кроме `id` и `class`, всё это сделать через регулярное выражение.

Comment: А вариант с созданием `HtmlElement` (без вставки в дерево документа) вы не рассматриваете? Почему? В текущей постановке очень похоже на [проблему XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-x-y-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-xy-problem).

Comment: [Для поиска тегов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433441/178988) почти годится, только надо выбор атрибутов доработать.

Answer (score 2):

Возможным несколько вариантов расстановки атрибутов внутри тега:

1. Сначала id потом class
2. Сначала class потом id
3. Только id
4. Только class
5. Ни id ни class

Рассмотрим все варианты.

```
re=/\<div.*?(( (id|class) *= *[^ >]*)(.*? ((id|class) *= *[^ >]*))?.*?)?\>/ig;
text='<div ttttt id=ghg dddd class=df >\n<div aaa class=sss udud id=asd dsf>\n<div aaa id=bbb ddd>sdf\n<div ddd class=sdf dsf>df\n<div asff>';
console.log(text.replace(re, '<div $2 $5 >'));
```

Результат

```
<div  id=ghg class=df >
<div  class=sss id=asd >
<div  id=bbb  >sdf
<div  class=sdf  >df
<div   >
```

Ограничения по регулярному выражению: значения id и class не должны содержать пробел или `>` внутри кавычек. Такие значения не допустимы:

```
id="papa mama"
class="cout>>>"
id=" myId"
```

В случае необходимости можно немного усложнить и убрать это ограничение заменив `[^ >]*` на `([^ >]*|(".*?"))`
В этом случае внутри кавычек не должно быть экранированной кавычки.