# Как удалить все HTML-теги регулярным выражением?

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение **(\<(/?[^>]+)>)**, которое оставляет HTML-тэги.
Как наоборот удалить все тэги, оставив только текст?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Так собственно её и можно использовать для чистки тегов, скормив в `sub`.

В Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\<(/?[^>]+)>)', '', '<b>Текст с <br/>тегами</b>')
'Текст с тегами'
```

В JavaScript:

```
>>> console.log('<b>Текст с <br/>тегами</b>'.replace(/(\<(\/?[^>]+)>)/g, ''))
"Текст с тегами"
```

Только надо обязательно помнить, что никакое регулярное выражение не сможет правильно обработать сломанный html:

```
>>> line = '<div> >>>2 + 3 < 6<br/>True <!-- коммен > тарий --></div><b'
>>> re.sub(r'(\<(/?[^>]+)>)', '', line)
' >>>2 + 3 True  тарий --><b'
```

И для такого дела лучше применять полноценные html-парсеры, а [регулярки к html-коду не подпускать вообще](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Комментарии надо в первую очередь удалять. Затем уже теги.

Comment: Активно поддержу идею использования хтмл-парсера, а не регулярок.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, а я по поводу парсера никаких возражений не только не высказывал, но и не имею. С другой строны, для многих конкретных задач вполне подойдёт простая регулярка.

Comment: @Qwertiy невалидному html-коду предварительное удаление комментариев не поможет. Дар для конкретных задач - если точно известна структура документа, если точно известна его (не)валидность, если надо вытащить конкретный кусок текста - регулярки могут подойти. Но если, например, приспичит фильтровать пользовательский ввод (а, подозреваю, это и хочет автор), то так делать уже опасно

Comment: Невалидному html'у поможет более строгое определение тегов (например, в моей регулярке требуются буквенно-цифроые символы после `<`). Удаление комментариев поможет от другого - оно повышает точность и избавляет от фокусов с синтаксисом.

Comment: Что касается фильтрации пользовательского ввода, то да, так делать не стоит (хотя, а зачем вообще удалять все теги, если их можно просто вывести как текст?). С другой стороны, безопасность от этого не страдает, поскольку ты можешь удалить больше чем надо, но не меньше. Или всё-таки можно подобрать конструкцию, чтобы удалилось меньше?

Comment: Ну, собственно, <b в конце моей строки никакая из приведенных на данный момент регулярок не удалит.

Comment: `<b` - он не закрыт, так что он не совсем тег, а в остальном моя справляется успешно. Впрочем, можно заменмить `>` на `(>|$)` - тогда вообще всё сойдётся: `var html = '<div> >>>2 + 3 < 6<br/>True <!-- коммен > тарий --></div><b';
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html;
div.textContent === html.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?--!?>/g, "").replace(/<\/?\w+[^>]*(>|$)/g, "")`

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну незакрытый тег — [уязвимость](https://cedricvb.be/post/wordpress-stored-xss-vulnerability-4-1-2/).

Comment: Поправил, добавив проверку на конец строки.

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда вот ещё: `2+3<6`; `2+3<`; `<<a>script>alert("XSS!")<<a>/script>`

Comment: Я подкорректировал ответ. А фокус в том, что извлечение текста браузерным парсером из твоего последнего примера тоже содержит скрипт. Так что от уязвимостей надо далать замену при выводе, а не химичить с выдиранием тегов.

Comment: Но в любом случае все приведённые регулярки могут терять полезный текст на специфических строках.) Кстати, учитывая, что даже html-парсер что-то обязательно потеряет, идея чистки от тегов изначально не очень хорошая.

Comment: Пока вижу только проблему со скобками в аттрибутах, но при этом текст не теряется, а остаётся. Предыдущие могли удалить лишнее, последняя - вроде не должна. Но я в принципе не вижу смысла чистить текст от тегов каким-либо образом. Только если часть тегов всё-таки разрешины для форматирования, а остальные надо удалить. Но я бы предпочёл bb-коды - самая удобная система форматирования, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 9):

На данный момент, наиболее близкая к браузерной версия:

```
function textByBrowser(html) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = html;
  return div.textContent;
}

function textByRegex(html) {
  return html.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?--!?>/g, "").replace(/<\/?[a-z][^>]*(>|$)/gi, "");
}

var tests = [
  '2+3<6',
  '2+3<',
  '<<a>script>alert("XSS!")<<a>/script>',
  '<div> >>>2 + 3 < 6<br/>True <!-- коммен > тарий --></div><b',
  '<script<b>>alert(1)</script</b>>',
  '<a\n>123\n</a>'
];

tests.map(textByBrowser) + "" == tests.map(textByRegex) // true
```

Наличие угловых скобок в аттрибутах обрабатывается некорректно:

```
textByBrowser('1<div data-smth=">">2</div>3') // 123
textByRegex('1<div data-smth=">">2</div>3') // 1">23
```

И с мнемониками надо разобраться по своему усмотрению:

```
textByBrowser("&lt;") // "<"
textByRegex("&lt;") // "&lt;"
```

Обращаю внимание, что ни один из способов получения текста не является защитой от XSS-атак. При выводе пользовательского текста на странице всегда надо применять экранирование.

```
console.log(textByBrowser('<<a>script>alert("XSS!")<<a>/script>'));
// <script>alert("XSS!")</script>
```

PS: Более ранняя версия ответа с другим кодом доступна в истории.

Comment: Может рекурсивно сделать баланс < и > ? тогда будет удаляться сломанная разметка

Comment: @ReinRaus, рекурсия в регулярках? Точно не в js.

Comment: @ReinRaus, кстати, а где должен быть баланс? Там надо другое править - более гибко обрабатывать содержимое атрибутов.

Comment: не помню. давно это было

Answer (score 3):

`(?:<).*?(?:>)` - вырезает все теги

Comment: Группы-то зачем?

Answer (score 2):

В php есть функция strip_tags - удаляет HTML и PHP тэги из строки

Answer (score 2):

Как по мне, более точное определение тега будет таким

В JavaScript:

```
<\/?[A-Za-z]+[^>]*>
```

Comment: От моего очень мало отличается...

Comment: Вообще говоря различия существенные, стандартные теги не могут начинаться с цифры и нижнего подчеркивания, также тег в начале идет без пробела. А ваша регулярка все это допускает.

Comment: Где? о_О Ты точно с моим ответом сравниваешь? У меня вот такая: `/<\/?[a-z][^>]*(>|$)/gi`

Comment: Да видимо напутал, не с вашим.
Ваш по лучше будет, но.

**Ваша:**
"[a-z]" - это только 1 символ из диапазона a-z, затем любой символ "[^>]" кроме ">" 0 или более раз, пока не встретит закрывающую кавычку или конец строки.

Ну как минимум конец строки это не закрытие тега "<f".
Во вторых, запрос типа "<f5454>" тоже прокатит, стандартных тегов таких нет, с цифрами, но может быть полезным если есть кастомные теги, конечно.

https://regexper.com/#%2F%3C%5C%2F%3F%5Ba-z%5D%5B%5E%3E%5D*%28%3E%7C%24%29%2Fgi

Comment: Хотя мой можно улучшить еще так
<\/?[A-Za-z]+?[^>]*?>

https://regexper.com/#%3C%5C%2F%3F%5BA-Za-z%5D%2B%3F%5B%5E%3E%5D*%3F%3E

Comment: Браузер считает, что конец строки завершает тег, если `>` не встретилась - мне ссылку в комментариях давали) А выкинуть просили все теги, а не только стандартные. По сути, твой плюс ничего не делает: после первой буквы можно оставшуюся часть строки отправить в [^>]*, поскольку между ними нет `\b` (точнее, распределятся они не так, но без групп это неважно).

Comment: "По сути, твой плюс ничего не делает: после первой буквы можно оставшуюся часть строки отправить в [^>]*," - это не верно, поскольку теги не могу содержать например знак доллара а ваша регулярка пропускает ... и тд.
В общем ладно делайте как хотите

Comment: `"<a$$$>".match(/<\/?[A-Za-z]+[^>]*>/)` - я про то, что твоя тоже находит совпадение. Достаточно одной буквы в начале, а плюс бесполезен.

Answer (score 1):

```
var htmlTage = "<p>Hello world</p>";

var regExp = /(<.*?>)/g

var result = htmlTage.replace(regExp, " ");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]