# Регулярное выражение берет последний закрывающийся тег

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Не правильно работает регулярное выражение, вернее его надо подправить чтобы оно все правильно делала.

```
<(.+?)>(.*)<\\/\\1>
```

Вот строчка

```
<0>0</0><ints2><0>0</0><10>10</10></ints2><10>10</10>
```

должно получится так

```
[1]=0
[2]=0`
```

То есть он взял `<0>0</0>`

но получается вот так

```
[1]=0
[2]=0</0><ints2><0>0
```

То есть он взял `<0>0</0><ints2><0>0</0>`

Или например:

```
<10>10</10><10>11</10>
```

Получится:

```
[1]=10
[2]=10</10><10>11
```

А должно:

```
[1]=10
[2]=10
```

Тоесть он ищет самый последний закрывающийся тег!
Когда мне нужно первый попавшийся закрывающий тег (у которого имя точно такоеже как у тега (по регулярке думаю понятно))

Comment: Не стоит использовать регулярки для парсинга XML.

Comment: Это не xml, это текст

Comment: XML по определению является текстом. Возьмите нормальный парсер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Добавь знак вопроса после звёздочки.
2. Используй регулярное выражение [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433441/178988).
3. А может имеет смысл воспользоваться нормальным парсером?

Comment: Тоочно! знак вопроса)) как я мучался, а оказалось просто, спасибо большое, p.s это не html, это не xml.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров: Если двое говорят вам, что вы пользуетесь неподходящим инструментом, подумайте, может быть, они правы? (И я тоже к ним присоединяюсь.)