# Python3 | Как найти все совпадающие предложения в тексте

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Работаю с `re`, у меня есть код:

```
import requests
import urllib3
import re
import grequests


def _brute_connection_(url, port, force):
    url = url
    port = int(port)
    force = int(force)

    dictionary = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm']
    keywords = ["[", "]", ";", "'", '"', "/", "|", ",", ".", "<", ">", '?', '-', '=', '_', '+', ':', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '`', '~']
    number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

    for samaphone_dict in dictionary:
        _brute_url_ = requests.get(url + samaphone_dict + str(keywords))
        print(_brute_url_.text)
        aa = re.findall(r'Warning', _brute_url_.text)
        print(aa)


_brute_connection_(url='http://www.bt-motors.ru/news.php?id=1', port=80, force=144)
```

Мне нужно чтобы мне выдало

```
Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/users/b/bt-motors/domains/bt-motors.myjino.ru/includes/menu.php on line 3 , 
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'includes/connect.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/zend-5.4/share/pear') in /home/users/b/bt-motors/domains/bt-motors.myjino.ru/news.php on line 2
```

и т.д.

То есть все совпадающие предложения в тексте. И как сделать на `grequests`? Он текст не принимает, хоть это и обертка над простым `requests`, но большинство там не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь [возможностью передавать в `findall` захватывающие группы (captured groups)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6018450/5812238). Каждый такой `Warning` оканчивается тегом `<br/>`, поэтому можно написать что-то вроде

```
warnings = re.findall(r'(<b>Warning.*)<br', _brute_url_.text)
```

Полный код:

```
import requests
import urllib3
import re
import grequests


def _brute_connection_(url, port, force):
    url = url
    port = int(port)
    force = int(force)

    dictionary = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm']
    keywords = ["[", "]", ";", "'", '"', "/", "|", ",", ".", "<", ">", '?', '-', '=', '_', '+', ':', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '`', '~']
    number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

    for samaphone_dict in dictionary:
        _brute_url_ = requests.get(url + samaphone_dict + str(keywords))
        warnings = re.findall(r'(<b>Warning.*)<br', _brute_url_.text)
        for warning in warnings:
            print(warning)


_brute_connection_(url='http://www.bt-motors.ru/news.php?id=1', port=80, force=144)
```

у меня выводит что-то вроде

```
<b>Warning</b>:  include(includes/connect.php): failed to open stream: Нет такого файла или каталога in <b>/home/users/b/bt-motors/domains/bt-motors.myjino.ru/news.php</b> on line <b>2</b>
<b>Warning</b>:  include(): Failed opening 'includes/connect.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/zend-5.4/share/pear') in <b>/home/users/b/bt-motors/domains/bt-motors.myjino.ru/news.php</b> on line <b>2</b>
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO) in <b>/home/users/b/bt-motors/domains/bt-motors.myjino.ru/includes/menu.php</b> on line <b>3</b>
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in <b>/home/users/b/bt-motors/domains/bt-motors.myjino.ru/includes/menu.php</b> on line <b>3</b>
```

Comment: действительно работает) Но как мне очистить текст от все <br></br> ? И можно ли собирать текст не находя всех тегов и атрибутов, допустим у меня есть тот же текст, но мне не надо приписывать <br><br> и т.д ?

Comment: @youhavenopass извини, что долго не отвечал. Тега `</br>` вроде не бывает, скорее всего ты хочешь очистить текст от всех `<b></b>`, что-нибудь вроде `warning.replace('<b>', '').replace('</b>', '')` не подойдёт?

Comment: пойдет)) но можно ли опять же при помощи re убрать эти скобки и т.д абсолютно ко всем тегам и т.д ? И у меня проблема с grequests, и вообще не малейшего понятия не имею почему у меня ошибка TypeError: 'AsyncRequest' object is not iterable

Comment: Насчёт grequests задай, пожалуйста, новый вопрос, так как я про grequests ничего не знаю. Про удаление всех тегов хорошо написано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433358/227016).

Comment: А как мне сделать так чтоб, если это сообщений было найдено то вывелось всего 1 раз ? Я помощью break не помогает

Comment: @youhavenopass может быть завести set строк, перед выводом проверять, есть ли строка в set, если нету то добавить строку в set и выводить её.

Comment: если честно, с set не когда в жизни не работал, не разу) Я вообще не имею понятия для чего она) Если можете, дайте в ответ или отредактируйте)

Comment: @youhavenopass, с set обязательно надо познакомиться, очень полезная структура данных, например можно почитать [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/mnozhestva-set-i-frozenset.html). В данном случае set нужен чтобы быстро проверять, встречалась ли строка раньше. Можно и обычный list использовать, но будет медленнее работать.