# Как удалить все теги кроме <img> регулярным выражением

Tags: javascript, jquery

Это функция удаляет все теги и оставляет внутренний тексты. Как сделать чтобы удалят все теги кроме `<img>` и оставлять внутренний тексты и сохранив позиция курсора?

```
html.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?--!?>/g, "").replace(/<\/?[a-z][^>]*(>|$)/gi, "");
```

```js
$('[contenteditable="true"]').bind('paste', function(e) {
  var text = $(this).html().replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?--!?>/g, "").replace(/<\/?[a-z][^>]*(>|$)/gi, "");
  $(this).html(text);
  // И почему то это работает после второй вставление и не сохраняет позиция курсора
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;padding:10px">Всталять теги сохранив позиция курсора</div>
```

Comment: Не надо делать такие вещ регулярным выражением, используйте нормальный HTML-парсер

Comment: Да, да, напишите парсер строк на 1000-2000 и его используйте :)

Comment: `/<\/?[a-z][^>]*(>|$)/gi` замените на `/<\/?(?!img(?:\s|>))[a-z][^>]*(>|$)/gi`

Comment: О, прикольно. Регулярка в вопросе как раз из моего ответа в другом вопросе))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как сделать чтобы удалят все теги кроме `<img>`

На основе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433441/178988

```
html.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?--!?>/g, "").replace(/<(?!img)\/?[a-z][^>]*(>|$)/gi, "")
//                                               ^^^^^^^
```

> и оставлять внутренний тексты и сохранив позиция курсора?

Вместо замены содержимого можно использовать css-стили, которые просто приведут к тому, что всё будет показываться как обычный текст: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454198/178988

А вообще, для сохранения позиции курсора можно покопать в сторону `Selection`.

Comment: Как раз регулярка не совпадает с моих комментарием :Р

Comment: @Visman, погоди... Я тут ответил, потом прочитал вопрос, теперь думаю. Но регулярка как раз нормальная же?

Comment: Ну если принять, что закрывающихся тегов </img> не бывает, то правильная :)

Comment: @Visman, закрывающий тег `</img>` невалиден для html. Можно закрывать только так: `<img ... />`, да и то необязательно. Если бы я хотел разрешить закрывающий тег, я бы поставил проверку после `\/?`, но зачем мне разрешать невалидные теги?

Comment: @Visman, вроде переоформил ответ.