# Как взять текст из элимента <div> и при этом не получить лишние теги?

Tags: javascript

Как при нажатии Enter не получить лишние теги?
 Как у соц. сети В контакте если не введено не чего то поле ввода остается пустым сообщение не добавляется!!! Если же нет то добавляется без лишних тегов!!!
Делаю так:

```
<div id="mess" class="mess" contenteditable="true" tabindex="0" data-placeholder="Введите сюда текст"></div>

$('#mess').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            var text = kemoji.getValue(KEmoji.HTML_VALUE);
            if (text == ''){
                document.getElementById('mess').innerHTML='';

            }else {
                let message = {
                    id: window.roomt,
                    uid:window.id,
                    name: myname,
                    msg: kemoji.getValue(KEmoji.HTML_VALUE),
                    ava: chimg,
                    color: color,
                    goto: window.goto,
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "roomUser/chatroom.php",
                    data: {myData: message},
                    success: function (response) {
                    }
                });
                websocket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
            }
            document.getElementById('mess').innerHTML='';
            window.goto='';
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Но не чего не выходит вместе с нажатием Enter приходит тег 
 как от него избавится?
[image: Вот такая картина даже при пустом поле ввода]

А нужно если поле пустое не выполнять ввода, и не добавлять тег 
!!!

Или может есть варианты как ни будь его убрать? Подскажите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: $("то, что приходит").text();

Comment: @Timur Musharapov Подскажите пожалуйста. А не будет лучше если я подсчитаю количество символов и уберу лишние!!! По тому как там есть и смаилы тег <img>  нужен а тег <br><br> приходит всегда вот как пример: var text = unescape('строка');
  var num = text.length;
  var ter = num --- 8;
  var t = (text.substr(0,ter));
  console.log (t);

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705352/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-img-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC