# Как проверить и выделить выбранные части, если в регулярном выражении нет определенного символа?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Мне бы хотелось, чтобы регулярное выражение выделяло html теги с attr. Я нашел одно Reg Exp на SO, но оно **НЕ** работает как надо. P.S (я парсшу html из markdown)

Пример:

Это регулярное выражение: `^ *(?!<[а-я][^ >/]* ?\/>)<([ а-я][^ >/]*) ?([^>]*)\/{0}>\ n?(\s*(?:<\1[^>]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>|(?!<\1)[\ s\S])*?)<\/\1>\ n*`

Из `<sup className="adsf" src="asdasd" onClick="e => console.log(e)">\* </sup>` Мне нужно выделить:

1. Tag: `sup`
2. Attrs: `className="adsf" src="asdasd" onClick="e =>console.log(e)"`
3. Content: `\*`

Это мой ожидаемый результат

Но на самом деле, у меня получается это (проверено с regex101.com):

1. Tag: `sup`
2. Attrs: `className="adsf" src="asdasd" onClick="e =`
3. Content: `console.log(e)">\*`

Пожалуйста, помогите мне с этой проблемой и ответьте мне, как это исправить.

P.S: Не судите строго, это мой первый вопрос на SO.

Comment: "но оно работает как надо" - супер, в чём вопрос?)

Comment: @EzioMercer К сожалению нет.. Он выделяет не до конца атрибуты, если есть стрелочная функция. Как это исправить - я не знаю, не силен в регулярных выражениях(

Comment: Я просто выделил ваше же предложение :)

Comment: @EzioMercer xD. Извиняюсь не заметил. Просто первое предложение с англоязычного SO скопировал (там меня уже послали, сказав что я идиот и надо делать через DOM Parser (я вообще на ноде это делаю))

Comment: Ну не буду так грубо выражаться, но они в общем правы. Не стоит пытаться парсить `html` регулярными выражениями. Я уверен на ноде должны быть инструменты для парсинга `html`-а

Comment: Вот буквально первый запрос из гугла (по крайней мере у меня первый) https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser

Comment: @EzioMercer Огромное спасибо, не догадался посмотреть парсеры. Нашел ответ здесь - [код](https://github.com/taoqf/node-html-parser/blob/main/src/nodes/html.ts). Также, хочу поблагодарить вас за то, что помогли мне и ответили на столь "своеобразный" вопрос. На англоязычном SO более токсичные люди :)

Comment: Обращайтесь! :)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433441/178988

Comment: @EzioMercer, токенизировать html регулярками вполне возможно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я не сказал, что невозможно (хотя где-то и читал на enSO большой пост что нельзя). Но тут скорее надо будет под каждый случай отдельно подстраиваться и потому насколько я понял не рекомендуют это делать

Comment: @EzioMercer, нельзя парсить, а токенизировать - можно. Это разные задачи.

Comment: @Qwertiy А, понял, буду знать :)

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо [@EzioMercer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1426821#comment2542835_1426821)

Регулярное выражение, которое мне помогло:

```
^ *(?!<[a-z][^ >/]* ?\/>)<([a-zA-Z][-.:0-9_a-zA-Z]*)((?:\s+[^>]*?(?:(?:'[^']*')|(?:"[^"]*"))?)*)\s*>\n?(\s*(?:<\1[^>]*?>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>|(?!<\1)[\s\S])*?)<\/\1>\n*
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433441/178988